# Console object replacing not working in javascript - PWA app

Tags: javascript

I have replaced the console object with the below code. My intention is to get all the logs written to the console and pass those to my logger component for sending to server
But when I tested it very few logs are passed to the logger component. Please help me identify the issue?

In the below code I have overridden almost all the functions in the console object.
Is there a chance that the browser provides different console objects for different components within the same app?

```
var console = (function (oldCons) {
        return {
          log: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.log(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          info: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.info(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          warn: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.warn(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          error: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.error(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          assert: function () {
            var msg = '';
            var tmp = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              if (typeof arguments[i] === 'object') {
                tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
              } else {
                tmp = arguments[i];
              }
              msg += '--' + tmp;
            }
            oldCons.log(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          clear: function () {
          },
          count: function () {
          },
          countReset: function () {
          },
          dir: function () {
            var msg = '';
            var tmp = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              if (typeof arguments[i] === 'object') {
                tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
              } else {
                tmp = arguments[i];
              }
              msg += '--' + tmp;
            }
            oldCons.log(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          },
          dirxml: function () {
          },
          group: function () {
          },
          groupCollapsed: function () {
          },
          groupEnd: function () {
          },
          table: function () {
          },
          time: function () {
          },
          timeEnd: function () {
          },
          timeLog: function () {
          },
          time: function () {
          },
          timeEnd: function () {
          },
          debug: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.error(msg);
            logger.debug(msg);
          },
          trace: function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              msg += '--' + arguments[i];
            }
            oldCons.trace(msg);
            logger.logError(msg);
          }
        };
      }(window.console));

      window.console = console;
```

Comment: A [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) could make this easier.

Comment: _"But when I tested it very few logs are passed to the logger component."_ - Where are the tests? What calls are missing? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: By testing I mean, when I compared the logs in the console and the logs passed to my logger component, I could see only a few logs are passed to the logger component.

Comment: `throw "bruh"` would have the equivalent of `console.error("Uncaught bruh")` but it wouldn't actually call `console.error`.. this concept is the same for a lot of things that get logged on the console by the system.. **SOOO**, if you own the site.. how about you just replace console logging with sending the log to your server one time

Comment: This is a mobile PWA app and the logs I am looking for is the framework logs